# Uploading files to Cloudinary using ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, file-upload, asp.net-core, cloudinary, iformfile

I'm trying to upload files (images, to be precise) to Cloudinary.
In Cloudinary's documentation for .NET ([Documentation](http://cloudinary.com/documentation/dotnet_integration)), it's said that files should be uploaded like this:

```
var uploadParams = new ImageUploadParams()
{
    File = new FileDescription(@"c:\sample.jpg")
};
var uploadResult = cloudinary.Upload(uploadParams);
```

So basically, I need file path to upload an image. When I hard-code the path it works, but I want the user be able to choose his own files, obviously.
The only way to get the files that I have found was using IFormFile, but the only way I can upload file using it is by uploading it to server first, and then getting the path of the uploaded file and forwarding it to Cloaudinary, but there must be a better way.

So how can I let user upload files to Cloudinary using ASP.NET Core?

Comment: see [File Uploads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads) section in ASP.NET Core documentation

Comment: Refer to this tutorial http://techcerberus.blogspot.com.ng/2017/10/cloudinary-in-c-cloudinary-is-market.html


`public ImageUploadResult UploadImage(HttpPostedFileBase file) { 
  if (file != null) {
    var uploadParams = new ImageUploadParams { 
       File = new FileDescription(file.FileName,  file.InputStream),
      Transformation = new     Transformation().Width(200).Height(200).Crop("thumb").Gravity("face")
    };
   
     var uploadResult = _cloudinary.Upload(uploadParams); 
    return uploadResult;
 }
 return null; 
}`

Answer (score 8):

Basically, Cloudinary allows you to upload files from Paths or from Streams.

For File Path:

```
var uploadParams = new ImageUploadParams()
        {
            File = new FileDescription(@"c:\sample.jpg")
        };
        var uploadResult = cloudinary.Upload(uploadParams);
```

For Stream:

```
HttpPostedFile file = fileInput.PostedFile;
var uploadParams = new ImageUploadParams()
{
    File = new FileDescription(file.FileName, file.InputStream),
};
var uploadResult = cloudinary.Upload(uploadParams);
```

This second method allows you to even post a byte[] image content or a Base64 String containing an image data which you can easily convert to a Stream for upload.

```
//data is a byte[]
    Stream stream = new MemoryStream(data);
            var cloudinary = Connect();
            var uploadParams = new ImageUploadParams()
            {
                File = new FileDescription(GetGuid.Short(), stream),
                PublicId = GetGuid.Short()
            };
            var uploadResult = cloudinary.Upload(uploadParams);
            return uploadResult.SecureUri.AbsoluteUri;
```

Comment: I am having a very similar issue here. In my case I am getting my file from the InputFile Blazor component and whenever I try to use the upload method, I get a System.Threading.CancellationToken exception

Comment: @Tito, Are you passing cancellation token to the method?

Answer (score -1):

You don't have to upload image to server.

You can't send them directly from the client to cloudinary.

Check their [documentation](http://cloudinary.com/documentation/jquery_integration#getting_started_guide) how to achieve this with Jquery.